# Generating Excel Documents with ASP.NET Website

Tags: asp.net, excel, office-automation

I have an ASP.NET application that helps the user create a Gridview with certain data in it. Once this table is generated I want the user to push a button and be able to save the table as an Excel document.There are two different methods I know of:

1. Using HtmlTextWriter with ContentType "application/vnd.ms-excel" to send the file as an HttpResponse. I use GridView1.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter) to render the gridview. This almost works, but the excel file always shows a warning when the file opens because the content doesn't match the extension. I have tried various content types to no avail. This makes sense I guess, because I'm using an HtmlWriter. It also doesn't seem a good practice.
2. The second thing I've tried is generating the Excel file using Office Automation. But for the file to be generated, I need to save it to disk and then read it again. From what I have read, this is the only way, because the Excel object only becomes a real Excel file once you save it. I found that the .saveas method from the Excel class would throw an exception because of write permissions, even if I tried to save in the App_Data folder. So I did some research and found that apparently Office Automation is discouraged for web services: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support,
>   Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended,
>   non-interactive client application or component (including ASP,
>   ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable
>   behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

There surely must be a save way to have a website generate an Excel file and offer it to the user!? I can't imagine that this problem is unsolved or so rare that nobody cares about it, but yet I can't find any good solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest (and best) way to create an excel file is by using epplus

[Epplus sample for webapplication](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample)

```
            using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo");

                //Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1
                ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(tbl, true);

                //Format the header for column 1-3
                using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["A1:C1"])
                {
                    rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                    rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;                      //Set Pattern for the background to Solid
                    rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(79, 129, 189));  //Set color to dark blue
                    rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.White);
                }

                //Example how to Format Column 1 as numeric 
                using (ExcelRange col = ws.Cells[2, 1, 2 + tbl.Rows.Count, 1])
                {
                    col.Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.00";
                    col.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right;
                }

                //Write it back to the client
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx");
                Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
}
```

Comment: That looks like a useful tool, but I'm righting this web app for my company and I don't think the GNU license is going to work out. From the lack of answers here and in other threads I have googled, I'm getting the impression there is no good way without 3rd party tools!? Is that really how it is?

Comment: epplus is the best way to do it, if you want a product then i can recomend soft artisans excel / office writer , but it is quite expensive

Comment: without 3rd party, yes well epplus is written in c# and .net so take a look at the source code and do the same thing your self...

Comment: I had a look at the Epplus page but couldn't find the code I need in all the source code that is on the page. I'm using the Excel class for now. It works, but I'm still not very happy about it because of the Microsoft notice and because I'm not a fan of the Office Automation Tools in general. Still thanks for trying to help.

Comment: you should not use automation of excel on a server